# CSS / HTML button:hover issue?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design and am leaning it to be able to run my own page and potentially more.  This may not be the right area  for this post or it might, but I have an issue that does not resolve by changing the color in css .button:hover of red to another color.  It changes the original button colour itself, but the rest of the text on most of the page still is red with hovering. Text is below, css first then html.  This is a tutorial that is being followed.  What is wrong with the linking/text, thanks.

```
/* 
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

above = every element and style = even auto top padding (reset)*/

body{ 
    background color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #555555;

    font font-family: Sans-Serif, monospace, serif, sans-serif, 
    Bookman Old Style, Ubuntu;

    font-size:16px; 
    font-weight: normal;

/*same as above --- em or px for line heights*/
    font: normal 16px Sans-Serif, monospace, serif, sans-serif, 
    Bookman Old Style, Ubuntu;

    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
        /* = removes underline of links,"a<>"
        is added later to links to standardise links styles and more =
        hover state -  active state - visited state - */
    color: #000;
}

a:hover{
    color: red;
}

a:active{
    color: green;
}

a:visited{
    /* removed color:black;  = interfering with link of button colour. */
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.button{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    border:none;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color:green;
    color:#fff;
}

.box-1{
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;

    border-right: 5px red solid;
    border-left: 5px red solid;
    border-top: 5px red solid;
    border-bottom: 5px red solid;
/* same as above in a shorter syntax for "borders, padding & margins" */
    border: 5px red solid;

/* shortcut color = #333 = same darkish "black"
 or use black/white/words...container is better as percentage
 therefore allowing movement scaling. */

 border-width: 3px;
 border-bottom-width: 10px;
border-top-style: dotted;

/* overwrites border above = 3, 10, dotted ... also "padding" = inside of border,
margin = outside of border*/

border: 5px red solid;

padding: 20px;
margin-top: 20px; 
/* overwrite is next for 20px top & bottom and 0 for right & left */
margin:20px 0;

}

.clr{
    clear:both;
}

.box-1 h1{

    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:0.2em;
    word-spacing:1em;
}

.box-2{
    border: 3px dotted #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.categories{
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
/* radius = rounded corners of "categories" */
}

.categories h2{
    text-align: center;
}

.categories ul{
    padding:0;      /* = reset to remove "auto-padding" */
    padding-left: 20px;   /* for check mark spacing*/
    list-style: square;
    list-style: none;
}

.categories li{
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #333;
    list-style-image: url('../images/check.png');
/* adjust size of image used in gimp or photo shop such as 10px */

}

.my-form{
    padding:20px;
}

.my-form .form-group{
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

.my-form label{
    display:block;
}

.my-form input[type="text"], .my-form textarea {
    padding:8px;
    width: 100%;   /* = any input = button = 100% width of the "container" 
    but text and textarea are targeted byt the added "type+++" ---
    
    .my-form [type="submit"] {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px 15px;
    border:none;  = was before "global button class" change above for all */
}

.block{
    float:left;
    width:33.3%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;  /* warning = this adds to void % = +10px (too wide = 2 rows created), therefore, next lines added */
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#main-block{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    background-color: #333;
    color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


..................

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Cheat Sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
        
<body>
    <div class="container"> <!-- c/ container starts here /// -->
        <div class="box-1">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-2">
        <h1>Goodbye World</h1>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="">read more</a>
        </div>

        <div class="categories">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#no-where-linked-page-location">Category 1</li>
                    <li><a href="#no-where-linked-page-location">Category 2</li>
                    <li><a href="#no-where-linked-page-location">Category 3</li>
                    <li><a href="#no-where-linked-page-location">Category 4</li>
                    <li><a href="test.html">Category 5</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    
        <form class="my-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>E-mail:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="message">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="">
        </form>

        <div class="block">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="clr">
            
        </div>

        <div id="main-block">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="clr"></div>

        <div class="p-box">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <h2>Goodbye</h2>
        </div>



    </div> <!--/ container ends here, also p-box means "positioning box". /// -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, all links should be green on hover?

Currently, the color green is only applied to the class button (`.button` in CSS) on hover. The links under "*Categories*" are not buttons, but links and they do not have the `button` class. So the style cannot be applied.

Links, since they have no class, use:

```
a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

It is therefore normal that the color is red on hover. If you want the color to turn green, change "red" to "green".

PS: there are several problems in the code.
At the start of CSS:

- we find `font font-family:`, you have to declare one or the other property, e.g: `font:` or `font-family:`.
- we find `background color`, there is not a space but a `-` like this `background-color`

In the HTML: links require a closing tag, e.g. `</a>`